# Windows 8.1, is there way to log into my OneDrive acct without changing local login

Tags: windows-8.1, login, onedrive

Using Windows 8.1, is there a way to log into my OneDrive account while continuing to log into my machine using my local signin so I can continue access everything on my LAN?  When I open OneDrive it seems to want me to change my machine login.  If I try to install OneDrive for Windows 7, the installation says there is a higher version already installed.  I could not find a way to uninstall the current Windows 8.1 OneDrive.

-rwg

Comment: This might be a duplicate, but I did not find it when searching for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. OneDrive will only log in using the Microsoft account you are logged into Windows 8.1 with.

Comment: Well that is sad.

Comment: @rwg Please accept (and upvote if you like) my answer so this question is marked as closed.

Comment: I did not accept this (until now) because I was hoping that another answer would show up that would tell me how to do this.

Comment: there is a product called syncdriver that will sync folders on my window 8 or window 10 with Onedrive without have microsoft own my machine by forcing me to login using their system  (remember hotmail?).  Also the offic product Onenote will sync without being forced to v=give up my local login.

Comment: I was not aware of that, as it is a third-party appication